# How to read text and get string to convert JSON file php

Tags: php, json, string, text

I want to get some string in text file and divide then converting to JSON file
this is my text file, data.txt

```
"5 minute input rate 134000 bits/sec, 164 packets/sec

5 minute output rate 1320000 bits/sec, 150 packets/sec"
```

I want get a string to array and make a JSON file maybe like this:

```
$time= "5 minute "
$input= "input rate 134000 bits/sec"
$output= "output rate 1320000 bits/sec"
$array[koneksi]= json_decode('[.".$time.":".$input.]');
```

this is my code in PHP

```
<?php
$lines = file('var/www/datakom/data.txt');
$title = 'data';
    foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
        echo htmlspecialchars($line) . "<br />\n"; }
?>
```

Please help me. thanks a lot

Comment: is the time interval unit always "minute" ?

Comment: please elaborate more what is your issues. where exactly you are stuck at ?

Comment: You might want to use the `header("Content-Type: application/json");` so then you don't need to use `<br />`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using a regex sth like this :

```
<?php

//helpfull function
function preg_grep_keys( $pattern, $input, $flags = 0 )
{
    $keys = preg_grep( $pattern, array_keys( $input ), $flags );
    $vals = array();
    foreach ( $keys as $key )
    {
        $vals[$key] = $input[$key];
    }
    return $vals;
}

function parseFile(){
      $pattern='/(?<time>\d+)\s+(?<time_unit>\w+)\s+(?<direction>\w+)\s+(.*?)(?<rate>\d+)\s+(?<rate_unit>\w+)(.*?)(?<packets>\d+)/i';
       $lines = file('var/www/datakom/data.txt');
       $title = 'data';
       $json_data=array();
       foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
         preg_match($pattern,$line,$result);
         $json_data[]=preg_grep_keys('/time|time_unit|direction|rate|rate_unit|packets/',$result);
       }

    return json_encode($json_data);
}

?>
```

you need to invoke parseFile() function to parse the file , which will return a json "string". I am not sure you need json string or array . You can change the return statement to return json string or two-dimentional array e.g

```
 return json_encode($json_data);

 or 

 return  $json_data;
```

Note: I have not tested it , please give it a try and let me know

Comment: how to read the second line, third line and more. my data.txt is dynamic that just only read 1 line. but thanks sakhunzai

Comment: @NawoAzig, check the for loop its parsing each line

Comment: If I had a much simpler text file with single entries each on a separate line how do I get the pattern working ? I tried $pattern='/(?<town>\d+)\s)/i';
TY

Comment: @landed I think your pattern should be sth like `$pattern='/(?<town>\w+)/i'`, I am sure town is not a digit (\d) , It would be word ,or whatever data its , you have to adapt pattern accordingly. And you dont need the extra `\s` at the end I assume

Answer (score 0):

quick & dirty ... without regex... assuming:

```
$out = "5 minute input rate 134000 bits/sec, 164 packets/sec"
```

is the string you want to create an array from in the following form:

```
array(
   'time'  => '5',
   'input' => '134000',
   'packets'=> '164'
);
```

a readable non-regex solution ( this can be done shorter but i want to make it obvious )

1.) getting the text from beginning to the first occurence of a delimiter string:

```
// find time time interval
$timeDelimiter =  " minute"               // set the delimiter
$timeEnd = strpos($out, $timeDelimiter);  // find the first occurence of delimiter
$time = substr($out, 0, $timeEnd));       // set time to substring before delimiter
```

now strip this part away from your string ...

```
$out = substr($out, $timeEnd + strlen($timeDelimiter)); // strip the processed part from $out
```

2.) getting the text between two delimiter strings

```
// find the input interval
$inputDelimiterStart = "input rate ";
$inputDelimiterEnd   = " bits/sec";
$inputStartPos       = strpos($out,  $inputDelimiterStart) + strlen($inputDelimiterStart); 
$inputEndPos         = strpos($out, $inputEndDelimiter);
$input               = substr($out, $inputStartPos, $inputEndPos);
```

then again strip away what you have already processed

```
$out = substr($out, $inputEndPos + strlen($inputDelimiterEnd));
```

3.) .... same game for the packets... ( im leaving it out here .. you get the idea )

now that you have $time, $input, $packets ... output the JSON like this:

```
echo json_encode(
    array(
         'time'    => $time,
         'input'   => $input,
         'packets' => $packets,
    )
);
```

You could wrap this stuff into a function with startDelimiter, endDelimiter arguments aswell and save some code here. The best solution is using regular expressions aka regex ... but obviously they are harder to learn and not that easy to debug if they don't work the way you want.